# Trying to Install PyDev 3 on Eclipse (Kepler) on Mac

Tags: python, eclipse, macos, pydev

I am trying to install PyDev 3 on Eclipse (Kepler) on my Mac running 10.8.5 (Mountain Lion) however every time I install it, PyDev never shows up on the side bar when I go to Eclipse > Preferences.

I have followed this tutorial here exactly but PyDev still does not show up. 
http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ACrmcGjqrJw

I have Python 3.3.3 installed as well as Java 7, as PyDev says its a requirement.

Not sure why I can't get PyDev to show up because I have done this before multiple times the exact same way I am doing it now. This is the first time I am getting this problem.

Let me know if you need me to add extra details so you can better understand the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Im going to answer my own question just incase anyone comes across this problem. I uninstalled PyDev and Eclipse, and then found an older version of PyDev (2.8). I then reinstalled Eclipse and then manually installed PyDev by downloading the zip file and extracting the files to their appropriate places.

Answer (score 0):

For really worked me in two mac computers so far was (I took PyDev 2.8):

1) Installing with the zip file:
The available locations for the zip files are:
http://sourceforge.net/projects/pydev/files/

2) Eclipse 3.4 onwards
Extract the contents of the zip file in the eclipse/dropins folder and restart Eclipse.

This is extracted from:
http://pydev.org/manual_101_install.html

Answer (score 0):

I also had this problem, wanted to use python3.4 as interpreter and it wasn't compatible with pydev 2.8 so after a few trials I found out that if you install pydev 2.5 everything works fine !! (At least on Eclipse Kepler).